# In Table view, how do I customize the background color of a selected row?

Tags: swift, swiftui, colors, swiftui-table

I'm making a macOS app using SwiftUI. I have a `Table` view. I have selection enabled but I can't find any way to customize the selection color - it's always blue.

My table looks something like this:

```
Table(of: MyObj.self, selection: $selectedID, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
        TableColumn("Column Name") { obj in
            // do some custom view
        }
        // ...
    } rows: {
        Foreach (model.items) { obj in
            TableRow(obj)
        }
    }
}
```

The selection color is always the royal blue color. This doesn't match with colors in my app, and colors of text and icons in the row don't look good against this blue color.

Comment: If I was using UIKit, the UITableView seems to be much more customizable but the app is using SwiftUI and at this point, I can't replace it.

I found this question (but no answer):https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75905708/how-to-customize-the-selected-rows-color-in-a-table-in-swiftui

Comment: It is likely the accent color or tint

Comment: Wow you're right!  I set the accent color (it was there but it was set to None) and that did it.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help in `Assets` there is an "AccentColor" color set. If you change that to your app color you won't have to adapt everything that automatically uses the default Apple Blue Accent color

Answer (score 1):

You can change the "AccentColor" in "Assets" to override the default Apple systemBlue accent color everywhere in your app.

Comment: I tried .accentColor as well as .tint, it didn't affect the table's highlight color.  But when I changed the actual AccentColor in the assets, that's what did the trick.  (Not quite sure what else in the app this will affect, though)

My structure is:
Table(of: MyObj.self, selection: $selectedID, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {

} rows: {
}
.tint(.green)

Comment: @DavidDworkin it will change little things light highlight colors, selection colors, etc.

Comment: One question - i set the AccentColor to #AEC9F1 but when I run the app, the color doesn't match.  If i look at the table row highlight with Digital Color Meter, it shows #95AED4
I'm not doing anything like mucking with opacity or anything, so I can't tell what I might be doing wrong

(For the color, I have it set to sRGB, 8-bit hex with the value I put, 100% opacity)

Comment: @DavidDworkin the color spectrum can sometimes affect what you see. Try using the dropper that comes with the color wheel. That is the best way to match.

Comment: not sure what you mean.  Picking the color is not the issue - in xcode, I set the accent color for light to #aec9f1, and for dark to #373c55.  
But when i run the app and select a row in my table, in light mode it is #95aed4, and in dark mode it is #1d2138 - totally not the colors I picked.  I don't have any funny opacity set.
I can only set the accent color by changing the asset - i tried adding .accentColor or .tint to the ContentView that contains the view with my table, or to the Table directly and it made no affect